# Can I blow insulation over exposed flex ducts?

Tags: hvac, garage, ducts

I hired some HVAC professionals to place new flex ducts above the kitchen after a soffit removal. I know putting conditioned ducts in the attic is terrible, but the ceilings were 7' and it felt like I was living as a hobbit. Could I spray some new fiberglass over the exposed ducts close to the ground or even wrap them with more batts? I understand the importance of keeping them as non-compressed as possible to keep the air flow. I'm in phoenix with a south-facing roof and it doesn't get humid here ever so I figure the risk of moisture around the ducts is minimal if I do this?

Location: Phoenix, AZ

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your choice. Near Houston TX, I insulated the garage the same ae the house and got insulated doors. I never wondered for a minute if i should have done it. The doors have the bonus of not making the rattling sheet metal sound as they open and close. I

Comment: Would do insulation of the garage walls and ceiling with proper ventilation of the attic, if you plan on being in the garage for some time.  Will probably want fan/s or open window/doors in the garage if working in it.

Comment: I've removed your second question. It was entirely a matter of opinion the way it was phrased, making it off topic. Also, ask just one question per post, please.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. At first I thought you wanted to add more attic insulation. Now I think you're asking about increasing R-value in the ducts themselves. Please revise to be more clear about your goals and concerns.

Comment: You have insulated ducts so other than beefing up the insulation at the T a radiant barrier would probably be the best option or better attic vents solar power may be a good way to go in your area.